# Config settings for active_merchant to be compatible with a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemerchant

I'm following http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant

How do I set the configuration settings to be compatible with a Rails 3 app.

I tried putting the following in `config/initializers/active_merchant.rb`

```
if Rails.env == 'development'
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
      :login     => 'seller12341234zxcv.foobar.com',
      :password  => 'pasword',
      :signature => 'abc123'
    )
  end
elsif Rails.env == 'test'
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::BogusGateway.new
  end
elsif Rails.env == 'production'
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
      :login     => 'seller12341234zxcv.foobar.com',
      :password  => 'pasword',
      :signature => 'abc123'
    )
  end
end
```

The following renders an error:

```
config/initializers/active_merchant.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just need to get rid of the `config.after_initialize do` block -- should initialize fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your environments file i.e config/environments/development.rb, production.rb , etc Just use

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
  ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
   :login     => 'seller12341234zxcv.foobar.com',
   :password  => 'pasword',
   :signature => 'abc123'
  )
end
```

Comment: Adding this code in the `config/environments/<environment>.rb` file is a rails 2 thing, and not fully compatible with rails 3. Ran into issues elsewhere while upgrading a rails 2.3 app because of this. Rails 3 way is to put all these config in an initializer file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `config.after_initialize` to `ApplicationName::Application.config.after_initialize` and it should be working.